# API Gateway Resource policy returning 403

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

So I'm trying to restrict access on API Gateway for one API endpoint for Auth0 to call when a user has signed Up.

I've tried a few permutations on this, the example below in my mind should work that doesn't.

I allow everything.
As a test, I specifically allowed one endpoint also.
Then I deny everyone the securedEnpoint
Then I allow auth0 IP addresses access to the securedEnd endpoint - my IP was also on that list I've removed it for security.

The securedEndpoint doesn't have an authorizer attached, with this policy applied ALL endpoints return 403 from APIG - I'm using serverless to deploy this, what you see below is the resulting JSON from the resource policy section in the APIG console.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "eu-west-2:ACCOUNT_ID:API_ID/*/*/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "eu-west-2:ACCOUNT_ID:API_ID/*/*/allowedEndPoint"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "eu-west-2:ACCOUNT_ID:API_ID/*/POST/securedEndpoint"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "eu-west-2:ACCOUNT_ID:API_ID/*/POST/securedEndpoint",
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "138.91.154.99",
                        "54.183.64.135",
                        "54.67.77.38",
                        "54.67.15.170",
                        "54.183.204.205",
                        "54.173.21.107",
                        "54.85.173.28",
                        "35.167.74.121",
                        "35.160.3.103",
                        "35.166.202.113",
                        "52.14.40.253",
                        "52.14.38.78",
                        "52.14.17.114",
                        "52.71.209.77",
                        "34.195.142.251",
                        "52.200.94.42"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```